# how to group sales data by 4 days from yesterday to start date in r?

Tags: r

```
Date       Sales
3/11/2017   1
3/12/2017   0
3/13/2017   40
3/14/2017   47
3/15/2017   83
3/16/2017   62
3/17/2017   13
3/18/2017   58
3/19/2017   27
3/20/2017   17
3/21/2017   71
3/22/2017   76
3/23/2017   8
3/24/2017   13
3/25/2017   97
3/26/2017   58
3/27/2017   80
3/28/2017   77
3/29/2017   31
3/30/2017   78
3/31/2017   0
4/1/2017    40
4/2/2017    58
4/3/2017    32
4/4/2017    31
4/5/2017    90
4/6/2017    35
4/7/2017    88
4/8/2017    16
4/9/2017    72
4/10/2017   39
4/11/2017   8
4/12/2017   88
4/13/2017   93
4/14/2017   57
4/15/2017   23
4/16/2017   15
4/17/2017   6
4/18/2017   91
4/19/2017   87
4/20/2017   44
```

Here current date is 20/04/2017, My question is grouping data from 19/04/2017 to 11/03/2017 with 4 equal parts with summation sales in r programming?

Eg :

```
library("xts")
ep <- endpoints(data, on = 'days', k = 4)
period.apply(data,ep,sum)
```

it's not working. However, its taking start date to current date but I need to geatherd data from yestderday (19/4/2017) to start date and split into 4 equal parts.

kindly anyone guide me soon.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base R has a function `cut.Date()` which is built for the purpose.

However, the question is not fully clear on what the OP intends. My understanding of the requirements supplied in Q and additional [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508857/how-to-group-sales-data-by-4-days-from-yesterday-to-start-date-in-r#comment74073030_43508994) is:

1. Take the sales data per day in `Book1` but leave out the current day, i.e., use only completed days.
2. Group the data in four equal *parts*, i.e., four periods containing an equal number of days. (Note that the title of the Q and the attempt to use `xts::endpoint()` with `k = 4` indicates that the OP might have a different intention to group the data in *periods of four days length* each.)
3. Summarize the sales figures by period

For the sake of brevity, `data.table` is used here for data manipulation and aggregation, `lubridate` for date manipulation

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# coerce to data.table, convert Date column from character to class Date,
# exclude the actual date
temp <- setDT(Book1)[, Date := mdy(Book1$Date)][Date != today()]

# cut the date range in four parts
temp[, start_date_of_period := cut.Date(Date, 4)]

temp
#          Date Sales start_date_of_period
# 1: 2017-03-11     1           2017-03-11
# 2: 2017-03-12     0           2017-03-11
# 3: 2017-03-13    40           2017-03-11
# ...
#38: 2017-04-17     6           2017-04-10
#39: 2017-04-18    91           2017-04-10
#40: 2017-04-19    87           2017-04-10
#          Date Sales start_date_of_period

# aggregate sales by period
temp[, .(n_days = .N, total_sales = sum(Sales)), by = start_date_of_period]
#   start_date_of_period n_days total_sales
#1:           2017-03-11     10         348
#2:           2017-03-21     10         589
#3:           2017-03-31     10         462
#4:           2017-04-10     10         507
```

Thanks to *chaining*, this can be put together in one statement without using a temporary variable:

```
setDT(Book1)[, Date := mdy(Book1$Date)][Date != today()][
  , start_date_of_period := cut.Date(Date, 4)][
    , .(n_days = .N, total_sales = sum(Sales)), by = start_date_of_period]
```

**Note** If you want to reproduce the result in the future, you will have to replace the call to `today()` which excludes the current day by `mdy("4/20/2017")` which is the last day in the sample data set supplied by the OP.